# Zsh configuration - line navigation à la VSCode

Tags: zsh

I actually already asked the question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1460360) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57195970). I am using VSCode and I have this nice behaviour: when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> from the end of the line, it stops at

```
foo/bar/test_wait_what
    ^   ^    ^    ^
```

and when I do <kbd>Delete</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, it deletes `what`, then `_`, then `wait`, etc.

I would like to do more or less the same with `zsh` (without "oh-my-zsh" because I am already using `zimfw`). Out of the box, it seems that it does not consider `_` as a word separator and for `/`, it deletes it at the same time.

I found some similar issues where they suggest to use `select-word-style bash`, but bash does not have the behaviour I want when deleting.

Also, I found it hard to find clear information on `zsh`, examples and so on, so if you have any suggestions on how I could have found an answer by myself, do not hesitate.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: One some systems, you need to install a `zsh-doc` package for the documentation to be available (in a format more useful than the man pages which are not appropriate). Then you can use `info zsh` and its index. (try `info zsh WORDCHARS` for instance).

Comment: @AndyDalton ok I did not know it was not recommended, I will keep that in mind. That being said, I finally got a working answer for a question I asked 6 months ago. TBH it was not clear which between stackoverflow, superuser and here was the best option. Do you think I should close the other questions ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the tip, but do you know any other source more accessible to start with ?

Comment: The [zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html), from the zsh authors is probably a good start (though a bit dated now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `_` and `/` from `$WORDCHARS` (or any other character you don't want to be considered as part of a word for those widgets that operate on *words*) and define a widget that removes either sequences of word or non-word characters to bind to <kbd>Alt+Del</kbd>

```
delete-word-or-non-word() {
  emulate -L zsh       # restore default zsh options locally to the function
  set -o extendedglob  # extended glob needed for the ## operator (locally)

  # ${var##pattern} ksh operator to remove the longest string that matches
  # the pattern off the start of $var. Here applied to $RBUFFER which in a
  # zle widget is the part of the line editor buffer to the right of the
  # cursor. [[:WORD:]] matches a *word* character (alnums + $WORDCHARS),
  # ## is *one or more* (like ERE's + or ksh's +(...))
  RBUFFER=${RBUFFER##([[:WORD:]]##|[^[:WORD:]]##)}
}

zle -N delete-word-or-non-word # define a new zle widget using that function

# bind that new widget
bindkey '\ed' delete-word-or-non-word      # Alt+D
bindkey '^[[3;3~' delete-word-or-non-word  # Alt+Del on xterm at least

WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/_]}  # remove _ and / from WORDCHARS
                               # using the ${var//pattern/replacement} ksh
                               # operator

WORDCHARS=                     # or make it empty so that the only *word*
                               # characters are alphanumerics
```

(that doesn't require `select-word-style`)

Comment: Thank you! It has been a while since I am struggling with this. Could you elaborate what does your code ? what is a widget for example ? I really know nothing about zsh except I like using it for several reasons... I would like to understand better to not get stuck and silly problems like this.

Comment: @PierreMarchand, see edit.  Within `info zsh`, you can press `i` (or `I`) to bring up the index prompt and type any of the topics above (completion is available) like `WORDCHARS`, `bindkey`, `zle`, `parameter expansion` to learn more about it.